# How often are inactive users removed?

Tags: discussion

Is there any timeframe as to when the moderators remove inactive users? Or it is just done randomly by any moderator during surfing the site?

Comment: What makes you think we do? Why is this a support question?

Comment: What should it be? I could not guess!

Comment: I think support means that you have a problem and that a staff member might need to look at it.  There are not many tags on meta - I would use 'discussion' unless you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, "ordinary" violation of the rules (e.g. illegal voting by using sock puppet accounts or friends, gaming the badge system, posting offensive comments etc) won't result in account deletion but rather in a [suspension](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) which is kind of warning and given manually by a moderator. First for a few days (often a week, but it varies) and if the user ignore the alerts sent to his/her email along with the suspension it can be for longer time periods.

Second, there is automated account deletion process described [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/):

> We **delete cookie-based unregistered accounts** when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>    **AND**
> 2. The user has less than 50 reputation, and no visible (not-deleted) posts
>
> We **delete OpenID registered accounts** when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited Stack Overflow in six months
>    **AND**
> 2. The user has only 1 reputation, no visible posts, and no other accounts on the network

Third, most user removals are result of their own request as far as I can tell. Users without acitivity can delete their account by simply clicking a "delete" link otherwise any user can request account removal, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

See related post: ["User was removed" Rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161241/user-was-removed-rules)

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

We don't remove inactive users in either a timeframe or randomly. Diamond moderators can suspend or delete user accounts but this is only used very rarely, usually only in the case of abuse of the account.

Comment: I saw several users were deleted in SE sites. So I thought so!

Comment: @Mistu4u - users delete themselves, or they are 'spam' accounts, or were the source of abuse etc.  'Normal' users are not deleted even if they are inactive.